# Path.Combine() behaviour with drive letters

Tags: c#

According to the official documentation regarding `Path.Combine` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Remarks**
>
> If path1 is not a drive reference (that is, "C:" or "D:") and does not end with a valid separator character as defined in DirectorySeparatorChar, AltDirectorySeparatorChar, or VolumeSeparatorChar, DirectorySeparatorChar is appended to path1 before concatenation.

This means that it will not add the `\`  after the drive letter, so this piece of code:

```
var path1 = @"c:";
var path2 = @"file.txt";
Path.Combine(path1, path2);
```

will produce `C:file.txt` which doesn't forcely point to a file `file.txt` placed in `c:`.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Perhaps because it is lowercase? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.volumeseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx I would use `var path1 = "c:\\"`;

Comment: I just did a test and can confirm that `C:\temp>start c:live_14_09_2017.txt` works (on my system). I believe that `c:file.txt` would likely mean file.txt in the current directory of the c drive. So in my case that file is in the temp directory (ie my current directory on c) and so it works. I sadly don't have any other drive letters available to test if this does indeed work if I was on the d drive but I think assuming that `path2` is a relative path on the c drive is probably a reasonable assumption.

Comment: `C:file.txt` is definitely a valid path in Windows, just as it was in DOS.

Comment: The documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) confirms @chris observations: `If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory" operation on that disk`

Comment: C:XXX is the path to XXX relative to the current working directory on C:

Comment: DOS drive letters -- the gift that keeps on giving. Although there are very few cases where you would want to *rely* on the ability to switch drives and not paths while on Windows, it's still there for backwards compatibility all the way back to DOS 1.0, which had drives but no directories. [Raymond Chen has the story](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563).

Comment: Maybe my question should have focused on the fact that the resulting path doesn't have to point to `c:\file.txt`

Comment: If you want to path to point to `c:\file.txt`, you have to combine `c:\ ` and `file.txt`. `c:file.txt` and `c:\file.txt` are both valid paths; the API can't guess which one you'd like (and, as you've pointed out, they are *not* equivalent).

Comment: @KevinGosse: Go ahead and make that an answer - you've got all the relevant references.

Comment: I agree, `c:readme.txt` is a valid path, a relic from the DOS days, where the OS keeps a "current folder" state for each drive in memory. It was common to issue commands like `copy d:readme.txt c:` which copies the file `readme.txt` from the current folder in the `D:` dirve to the current folder in the `C:` drive.

Comment: note, seems the example shown at the related Win32 function is either wrong or that function works differently (and adds the backslash to the drive designator) - https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Path.Combine` works that way because `c:file.txt` is actually a valid path.

According to [Microsoft documentation on NTFS paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory" operation on that disk.

In a nutshell, `c:file.txt` will search the file in the current directory of the C: drive, while `c:\file.txt` will search the file at the root folder of the drive (ignoring the current directory).

Since `Path.Combine` has no way to know what was the behavior you expected, it cannot automatically add backslashes.

Comment: Retrocomputing note: These per-drive current directories are a left-over from DOS 2.0, Win32 no longer has them and cmd.exe simulates them. See [Raymond Chen: Why does each drive have its own current directory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563)

Comment: @Heinzi that "Old new thing" article now has moved to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563 (don't you love https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Answer (score 6):

It's in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If `path1` is **not** a drive reference (that is, "C:" or "D:") and does **not** end with a valid separator character [..], `DirectorySeparatorChar` is appended to `path1` before concatenation.

So your first path, which is the drive letter, does not get a directory separator appended.

Answer (score 5):

The path `c:` and `c:\` are not the same.

- `c:` is a drive specification, and the OS appends the current folder when needed.
- `c:\` is the root folder of a drive, as in `c:` + `\`