# Why is the Path class adding a '/' to the filename?

Tags: c#, string, io

Why is the Path class adding a '/' to the filename?

```
        var file = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:", "Users", "Don", "test.xml");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Hovering over the file variable in the first line is:

```
        "C:/Users/Don/test.xml"
```

Then the second line executes with this as the path in the error message(& fails - obviously):

```
        "/C:/Users/Don/test.xml"
```

Comment: The result of `System.IO.Path.Combine("C:", "Users", "Don", "test.xml");` is `C:Users\Don\test.xml` (I don't think Path.Combine understands 'drive letters') - so I'm confused as to why you say you get forward-slashes?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are seeing forward slashes? - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1JcJ1K

Comment: Yes. That is the exact string returned. I have used the Path class for a long time. This is making no sense.

Comment: Could you verify this happens on other computers too? Because it could jsut be a plain old OS Installation issue.

Comment: I don't have a different one to test on.

Comment: I think your issues comes down to Path not recognizing this is a File Sytem Path, but asumes it is a **Network** path. Try this one: System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\", "Users", "Don", "test.xml")

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [Path.Combine() behaviour with drive letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382183/path-combine-behaviour-with-drive-letters)

Comment: Even if I use one string it is still putting the forward slash in front.

Comment: It is an Xamarin project, but I don't think that's a concern. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Have you tried solution by @christopher? It seems to work properly. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPccyu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path.Combine() behaviour with drive letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382183/path-combine-behaviour-with-drive-letters)